# PDF Sharp, Image stretch across multiple page

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap, pdfsharp

Im trying to allow users to save/view a gantt chart using PDF Sharp, my problem is when a user selects too many rows the image gets compressed and is unreadable, is there a way i can allow/set the image to stretch across multiple pages?

So im creating two images combining them then outputting to a pdf page, I have tried setting the page width to a higher but this didnt work.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width + imageTest.Width, Math.Max(image.Height, imageTest.Height));
        using (Graphics combineG = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            combineG.DrawImage(imageTest, 0, 0);
            combineG.DrawImage(image, imageTest.Width, 0);
        }

        //convert to pdf
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
        document.Info.Title = "Holiday_Year " + year + "&Quarter " + quarter;

        PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
        page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
        XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 20, XFontStyle.BoldItalic);

        gfx.DrawImage(bitmap, new XRect(0, 100, page.Width, 100));

        gfx.DrawString("Holiday - Quarter " + quarter + " & Year " + year, font, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, 40), XStringFormats.Center);


        byte[] fileContents = null;
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        document.Save(memoryStream, true);
        fileContents = memoryStream.ToArray();

        memoryStream.Close();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;    filename=IEMS-Holiday.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(fileContents);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Don't know how to get this done using pdfsharp, but I'm sure iTextSharp allows you to use a large set of Page Size. I think that might help you solve the problem.

Comment: ok thank you, I will have a look at iTextSharp

Comment: This link might help you. : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in

Comment: PDFsharp also supports custom page sizes. For tables with many columns we increase the width of the page. Just use `page.Width = XUnit.FromCentimeter(50);` after calling `PdfPage page = document.AddPage();` (instead of "FromCentimeter(50)" use the width you need).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: PDFsharp has no built-in feature that allows images to spread across multiple pages.

An image can be drawn on several pages at different positions, displaying different parts of the image. After printing, these pages could be stitched together. The image will be included in the PDF file only once

PDFsharp supports custom page sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have sort of resolved my issue, i added in this code to check the image height, then output to the correct page size.

```
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
        if (image.Height > 1000)
        {
            page.Size = PageSize.A1;
        }
        else
        {
            page.Size = PageSize.A2;
        }
```

this way it put a large image onto a A1 page etc, then i let adobe figure out how to print the page, seems to work well on viewing and printing

Comment: Could this lead to pages with large empty areas? Custom page sizes would reduce those large empty areas.

Comment: ok so your suggesting i get the image height and width then create a custom page with those dimensions, i didnt think of that. its a good idea i will give it a go

Answer (score 0):

Took me a little while to get the numbers right, but here is what I got and seems to take a single image that is as long as you need it and cuts it up into smaller chunks, placing each chunk on their own page.  Of course you will need to adjust the width depending on how much your doing, but again, it's just playing with the numbers.

```
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
            XImage img = XImage.FromFile(ImgPath);

            double captureHeight = 610;
            double captureWidth = 790;
            double totalHeight = img.PixelHeight / 1.5;
            double totalWidth = img.PixelWidth;

            PdfPage page = null;
            int i = 0;
            double saveHeight = 0;
            while (saveHeight < totalHeight)
            {
                page = new PdfPage();
                page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter;
                page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape;
                doc.Pages.Add(page);

                XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[i]);
                xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, (-i * captureHeight), captureWidth, totalHeight);
                saveHeight += captureHeight;
                i++;
            }

            doc.Save(PdfPath);
            doc.Close();
```